# Add aspects to Typescript class

Tags: typescript, object

Let's say we have a parent class `Item`, and two subclasses `Donation` and `Sale`. So far so good. Since I don't want to implement same behavior in both subclasses, I'm going with this way of representing them :

```js
abstract class Item {
  commonMethodToBothSubclasses() {
    // do something
  }
}

class Donation extends Item {}
class Sale extends Item {}
```

However, now I need to represent the "closed" version of those items. I could just add a `closed` (boolean) property in the parent, but I'd like my classes to be most expressive about methods they expose. So the "closed" versions of items will have some methods the "opened" version won't have.

One way of doing it is to create yet two more subclasses, like :

```js
class ClosedDonation extends Donation {}
class ClosedSale extends Sale {}
```

but I may have more properties to "express" like that, and I can't create all possible variations as classes. Furthermore, I'd like to force the `closed` property of those classes either to `false` for open ones, and `closed` for the others. And so on for other properties I may be interested with.

I was thinking of something representing aspects (like `Closed`, `Reserved`, `Adopted`, etc.), but I can't find a way to make it work. Something like :

```js
// Won't work
class (or whatever) Closed {
  closed() { return true; }
} 
class ClosedDonation extends Donation & Closed {}
```

Typescript seems to be a powerful language, so there maybe a (simple ?) way to achieve that.

Any way I can make this work ?

Comment: TypeScript does not support multiple inheritance, mixins, traits, or any similar constructs.

Comment: @nucleartux [ahem...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)

Comment: Yeah, but you are basically writing them from scratch. But you're right, my mistake.

Comment: Hey Alexandre, you haven't posted enough code to say for sure but mixins are most likely your best bet, see the link in my earlier comment.